# getJSON different line options

Tags: highcharts

Trying to create a chart with 1 dashed line and solid lines. I've only ever created a chart in which all the lines were styled the same. I'm using the getJSON method any everything works well, however I would like to individually style one of the lines. I thought I would be able to add something to the empty series section within options - but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'spline',
                marginBottom: 100

            },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [],
            },
            series: []
        }

        $.getJSON("php/mysqldata.php", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            options.series[1] = json[2];
            options.series[2] = json[3];
            options.series[3] = json[4];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add style information in that way (for example for second serie).

```
options.series[1] = json[2];
options.series[1].dashstyle = 'Dash';
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding correctly, are you saying this should work (only add the one line?)             $.getJSON("php/trend.php", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                options.series[1] = json[2];
    options.series[1].dashstyle = 'Dash';
    options.series[2] = json[3];
    options.series[3] = json[4];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });

Comment: Yes then that serie will include dash style for particular serie.